# ValueError: Cannot convert argument type <type 'bool'> to rgba array?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am learning to draw scatter using matplotlib. However, there is a bug and it seems related with the color argument. Could anyone explain me the mistake? I googled but no answer found. Thanks in advance.

```
xActA = range(10)
yActA = np.random.randn(10)
xActQ = range(10)
yActQ = np.random.randn(10)
xRa = np.random.randn(10)
yRa = np.random.randn(10)

f1 = figure(1)
scatter(xActA, yActA, c ='b', marker = 'o', facecolors = True, label = 'Answers')
scatter(xActQ, yActQ,   c ='r', marker = 'o', facecolors = True, label = 'Questions')
xscale('log')
yscale('log')
title('User activity')
xlabel('Number of posts')
ylabel('Number of users')
legend()
f1.show()
f1.savefig('figure7_test.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving facecolors a boolean.
The parameter is defined as:

```
facecolor or facecolors: matplotlib color arg or sequence of rgba tuples
```

Just make `facecolor = None` and it will work. You probably dont want this because you get the same color for the two plots. If you eliminate the parameter you will get automatic colors. If still you need custom colors the easiest way is to indicate them as matplotlib colors ('yellow, 'red', etc)

Comment: Thanks. I changed my code to:  ax1 = scatter(xActA, yActA, color = 'blue',s = 20), and there is a new error: return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.  And there is a plot with no scatter points but anything else in it. Could you tell me what is the mistake? Many thanks.

Comment: @AnneS it is difficult to say from the data you give. With those changes it still should work. So the problem is elsewhere you are not showing. You should post your new code and the **full** traceback in another question. But first, try to understand the program when it works and analyze what you changed to make it fail

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are supposed to supply an array of color values for the `facecolors` parameter, not `True`.